# Auto-Delete Old Document Library Items

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, cleanup

In SharePoint 2016, some libraries can grow to become unnecessarily large.  What I would like to do is implement a reoccurring job, perhaps daily, to clean up anything older than X days.

Is that possible using core SharePoint functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Document Retention Policies to achieve such a behaviour.

See here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-EB501FE9-2EF6-4150-945A-65A6451EE9E9